# How to find dynamically created QLineEdit when pressing QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to save the value is entered in a QLineEdit.
I am creating the layout using this function:

```
QHBoxLayout* MainWindow::CreateTbSettingLayout(QString title, QString desc, QString slot, QString unit){
    QHBoxLayout * setting = new QHBoxLayout;

    QLabel *titleLabel = new QLabel(title);
    titleLabel->setMaximumWidth(100);
    QLineEdit *settingTb = new QLineEdit;     
    settingTb->setMaximumWidth(200);    
    QLabel *unitLabel = new QLabel(unit);
    unitLabel->setMaximumWidth(50);
    QPushButton *setButton = new QPushButton(">>");    

    setting->setProperty("description", desc);
    
    connect(setButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_Setting_clicked()));
    setting->addWidget(titleLabel, Qt::AlignCenter);
    setting->addWidget(settingTb);
    setting->addWidget(unitLabel, Qt::AlignCenter);
    setting->addWidget(setButton);

    return setting;
}
```

I connected a slot to my QPushButton.My slot is below:

```
void MainWindow::on_Setting_clicked(){
    auto button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); 
}
```

I could not find any way to reach settingTb widget in the slot above.

Comment: I'm assumig the layout gets added to your window. Did you try [findChild()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild)?
Also a bit OT, but if you're using Qt5 please use the new signal-slot syntax.

Comment: I am using Qt4. I could not run findChild() method.

Comment: What do you mean? Didn't compile, did not exist or did not return the right thing?

Comment: I want to get the text of the QLineEdit which I created it as settingTb

Comment: Why not just make `settingTb` a member of the `MainWindow` class?

Comment: I am planning to create lots of this layout. I do not want to create every item as global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lambda function to solve this.

```
QHBoxLayout * Gui::CreateTbSettingLayout(QString title, QString desc, QString unit) {
    QHBoxLayout * setting = new QHBoxLayout;

    QLabel *titleLabel = new QLabel(title);
    titleLabel->setMaximumWidth(100);
    QLineEdit *settingTb = new QLineEdit;
    settingTb->setMaximumWidth(200);
    QLabel *unitLabel = new QLabel(unit);
    unitLabel->setMaximumWidth(50);
    QPushButton *setButton = new QPushButton(">>");

    setting->setProperty("description", desc);

    setting->addWidget(titleLabel, Qt::AlignCenter);
    setting->addWidget(settingTb);
    setting->addWidget(unitLabel, Qt::AlignCenter);
    setting->addWidget(setButton);
    QObject::connect(setButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [settingTb](){
       std::cout << settingTb->text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    });
```

Comment: Disclaimer I'm quite new to c++ so this might be terrible advice.

Comment: That is the answer that I look for. Thank you.